# Need Assistance with Syntax Error: Expected Expression But Found Command Name

Tags: applescript

So I've never used applescripts before, and I don't know how to code.

I'm trying to use this script I found online, but I've been getting "Syntax Error: Expected Expression But Found Command Name"

any help would be appreciated

Code:

```
on idle
  tell application "System Events"
    tell current location of network preferences
      set myConnection to the service "BTGuard”
      if current configuration of myConnection is not connected then
        try
          tell application "transmission"
            quit
          end tell
          connect myConnection
          –say "Retrying connection"
        end try
      else
        tell application "transmission"
          run
        end tell
      end if
    end tell
    return 1
  end tell
end idle
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have some curly quotes closing the **BTGuard** string (probably a result of copying formatted text from someplace such as a web page) - the fix for that is changing the quotes to the normal straight ones.  The other syntax problem is the comment character for the say statement - to comment a line like that, use either **--** or the **#** character.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you know nothing about applescript I'll ask... do you realize that this is a special applescript called a "stay-open" applescript? This means you must save it as an application and check the "stay-open" box for it to work properly.